# apex:inputField not working properly on Salesforce1 lightning app after clicking on it

Tags: visualforce, lightning-apps, ios, inputfield

I created a simple Lightning Salesforce1 app based on a custom VF page. App is done for iPhone/iOS devices.
Among others, in this VF page I added an editable box using the apex:inputField method, so that people cann add, delete or edit the information which is there.

Code is very simple, find it below:

```
<apex:inputField style="width:250px;height:50px" id="Status" required="false" value="{!account.Last_Status__c}" />
```

See "Current_Status" field in the screenshot below:
[image]

At the first click in the box, everything works just fine. I am able to delete, add or edit content in the box highlited in red in the above image.
But **whenever I click in the box AGAIN while in the text editor context** (see screenshot below) **the cursor is blocked, I cannot do any modifications anymore** (apart from eventually clicking on "*Select*", "*Select all*" or "*Copy || Paste*" options) **and the only option I have left is pressing the Done button**. After that, clicking again in the box things will work again until a new click is done in the box while in the text editor, and so on. **How could I solve this issue?**

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone who will take some time to look at this and advice.

Kind regards,

Francesco ALFEO

Comment: try using apex:input instead of apex:inputField .. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_user_input.htm

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, but it doesn't work in my case as it doesn't support the "value" attribute..

Comment: apex:input has value attribute. but you cannot bind it to an SObject Field. you can store the account.Last_Status__c field into a controller variable and then bind that variable to value attribute of your apex:input

Comment: Hello and thanks again Vamsi, I did what you suggested but problem is exactly the same as before. Moreover the text window has this "Go" button which behavior I don't like at all.. So, for now, keeping my previous solution (unless there is something I'm still missing here). Code snippet below:
- VF PAGE:
<apex:input style="width:250px;height:50px" id="Status" required="false" value="{!Current_Status}" />
- controller:
public String Current_Status {get; set;}
[...]
Current_Status = account.Last_Status__c;

Any other ideas? :) Francesco

Answer (score 1):

So I worked on this a while ago, and the issue is because of the UIWebView on the native iOS side. UIWebView if you're not familiar is the component used to embed web pages in an iOS app.

The phone just has this issue, and there wasn't anything we could do to work around it.

The solution will be for Salesforce to upgrade to the WKWebView, but I'm unsure when that will happen. WKWebView had some bugs that prevented us from being able to support it last I heard.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback Kris! Yes, I was starting to have the same feeling too unfortunately..

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to the fact that Visualforce pages within Salesforce1 (and Lightning apps in general) are embedded within an `iframe`. Touch events fired on the input, after initial focus, cause the `iframe` to lose focus and the parent window receives focus instead.

I found a workaround that recommended responding to the `keydown` event and then restoring focus back to the `iframe` window. I have modified this (and found better results) from responding to the `touchend` event and then restoring focus:

```
window.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
     window.focus();
});
```

Here is some more information regarding this issue and the original workaround (using the `keydown` event):

- https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC
- http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2527401